# Assignments in integers and lists

Tags: python-3.x

```
a=2
b=3
a=b
a=a+12
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output :

```
15
3
```

When i did this kind of thing in lists:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[4,5,6,7]
list1=list2
list1.append(12523)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7, 12523]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 12523]
```

Whenever i changed the value of a , b doesn't change at all.But in the second when i changed the list1 , list2 changes automatically.Can I ask why this happens ?

Comment: It's because `list1` and `list2` refers to the same list once you do `list1=list2`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the **data type** used, first you have `a = b` (both **integers**, **primitive types**) , as such what will happen in `a = b` is `a = 3`. In the second case you have a list *(not a primitive type)* ,`list1 = list2` list1 will point to the **same place in memory** as list2 is pointing to, so any change you make will change the place in memory that both list1 and list2 are pointing towards